# Java Parsing JSON with GSON

Tags: java, json

I am new to Java and JSON and I'm trying to parse the following JSON using GSON. However, I am having a problem in that I don't have any errors but the object is just empty.

```
{
    "pac": [
        {
            "customerName": "TEST"
        }
    ]
}
```

This class is what im trying to make an object of:

```
public class customer{

/** The customer name. */
private String customerName;

/**
 * Gets the customer name.
 *
 * @return the customer name
 */
public String getCustomerName() {
    return customerName;
}

/**
 * Sets the customer name.
 *
 * @param customerName the new customer name
 */
public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
    this.customerName = customerName;
}
```

I'm using this to try and parse:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
customer i = gson.fromJson(jsonFile, customer.class);
```

I would appriciate if you guys had any tips.

Comment: Your JSON file is not in proper format check http://json.org/example .

Comment: sorry that was an error when i posted the correct json is now in the question

Comment: @JishnuPrathap it is correct JSON, that it isn't formatted correctly doesn't matter, or at least shouldn't matter for any parser

Comment: @engineercoding format matter.. (not talking about spaces and indent) and OP has updated the JSON (if you saw his comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON show that there is an Object that have a property `pac`.

This property `pac` is an Array of customer

So you could try with :

```
public class Customers {

    public List<customer> pac; // List from java.util

}
```

and then

```
Customers i = gson.fromJson(jsonFile, Customers.class);
```